# Specialized Rock Hopper (1987) - Service

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, shimano, vintage

I was wondering if anyone might have a service manual of some description for a vintage Specialized Rock Hopper(1987 - Yellow)?

I have googled this for hours and hours and have tried contacting Specialized directly but no dice. I need to find out how to remove the rear brake, there appears to be something (perhaps a hidden pin) holding it to the bike. I really need to find out how to remove this, and I really don't want to pay the LBS for what could be a simple fix (colour me stingy).

As you can see, I've got a lot of work ahead of me to make this bike cosmetically sound, but the brakes are the only mechanical failing... Ideally I'd like to take them off to give them a deep clean, and to lubricate each part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Bill

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Could you post some images of your rear brake to illustrate how it looks like. Possibly it isn't a thing special to your bike but a rather standard thing...

Answer (score 1):

These are just old U-Brakes (installed at the chain stays as was cool for part of the late 80s). You just need to unbolt them from the studs (maybe hit it with some penetrating oil to help loosen it oFF the studs). Unfortunately due to the placement of the U brake , you're going to need to get another u brake since you won't be able to mount a normal brake that way.

Comment: A bike shop (the older and crustier the better) may have a replacement used U-brake in their junk bin.

Comment: Or ebay. They're on ebay a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your answer was answered yet; I found blow ups of bicycle parts for 1987 Rockhopper at this website:

http://mauisvintage.blogspot.com/2010/06/exploded-shimano-parts-diagrams-for.html